# What's throwing off my str_word_count?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP's function to count the number of words from a textarea via POST...

The issue is that if I do a post back to my file and output the word count it is different than if I copy and paste the same text into my PHP script to evaluate the word count.

What is throwing off the number? There is difference of 6 words, incidentally there are 6 double line breaks in the textarea as well.

How do I minimize this difference?

Comment: Try setting the second parameter `str_word_count($data, 1)` so it will return an array of all the words it encountered, then `var_dump()` that array and see what weird thing it's putting in there.

Comment: You just answered your own question while asking it.

Comment: Okay I think the issue is with the weird characters in the text area, there are a bunch of `“` which I believe are throwing off the count...what do I do with theses? I tried htmlentities but it is throwing the count off even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your line breaks are in HTML-form, you could use something like [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

If they aren't, I suspect an issue with encoding. Maybe an combination of stripslashes, utf8_encode or utf8_decode could solve this wrong counted words.

As an last resort you could use some regular expression to filter anything but [a-zA-Z] and spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the line breaks and tags altogether:

```
str_word_count(str_replace('<br>', '', nl2br(strip_tags($data))));
```

Or I guess this is better:

```
str_word_count(strip_tags(nl2br($data)));
```